# I'm confused about how expansion is happening here

Tags: tables, macros, expansion, etoolbox, pgffor

I was really pleased that I could come up with a means of [building the contents of a `tabular` environment using `\foreach \x in {...} {...}` structure.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/135839/22413)

But I was curious about what exactly it would take to break my code.  Here's my preamble, which works for generally *non-complex* content (whatever that's supposed to mean):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{pgfkeys,pgffor}

\pgfkeys{/ae/agenda/.cd,
  items for the agenda/.initial=,
  title/.initial=,
} 
\def\aeset#1{\pgfkeys{/ae/agenda/.cd,#1}}
\def\aeget#1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/ae/agenda/#1}}

\makeatletter

\newcounter{agendaitemcounter}
\def\agenda@item@number{%%
  \stepcounter{agendaitemcounter}%%
  \arabic{agendaitemcounter}.)}

\def\full@agenda{}
\long\def\build@agenda{%%
  \foreach \x in \list@of@agenda@items {
    \xdef\full@agenda{%%
      \expandonce\full@agenda
      \expandonce\agenda@item@number
      \expandonce\aeamp
      \expandonce\x
      \noexpand\\
      \noexpand\midrule}
  }}

\def\setagenda#1{%%
  \bgroup
  \aeset{#1}%%
  \edef\list@of@agenda@items{\aeget{items for the agenda}}%%
  \build@agenda
  \begin{minipage}[t]{4in}\centering
    {\large \aeget{title}}%%
    \par\vspace{1ex}
    \begin{tabular}{cp{3in}}\toprule
      \full@agenda          \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%%
  \end{minipage}%%
  \setcounter{agendaitemcounter}{0}%%
  \egroup
  \def\full@agenda{}%%
  }

\makeatother

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}

\def\aeamp{&}
\def\aepar{\par}
\def\dollars#1{\$#1}%$
\def\mypoly{\[x^2+1\]}

\pagestyle{empty}
```

So, I started playing with things to see where the macros in the preamble would break:  it wasn't too hard to find something.

The example code below compiles fine as written with the above preamble (except for the one commented-out line that contains `\noexpand\par`).
However, if I start removing `\noexpand` commands from these *working* lines, errors start popping up.

What  I can't quite understand is why certain structures don't break (e.g. `\frac{...}{...}`, `x^2`, and `\infty`) while other---superficially similar or simpler?---structures (e.g. `\cos` or `\$`) do break my code.

```
\begin{document}

\setagenda{
  title={To-do list},
  items for the agenda={%%
    {Line of random content, but nothing too fancy.},
    {Not too involved math: $x\cdot y$ },
    {A bit more involved, but it works! $\displaystyle{}\frac{1}{2d}$ },
    { Random collection of math symbols: $\inf \infty x^2+x$ },
    %% I need to use `\noexpand` to avoid getting an error.
    {This line works!\noexpand\aepar Hello world }
    %%{This line fails!\noexpand\par Hello world }
    { what follows fails without \noexpand\texttt{noexpand}},
    { Trying something which covers multiple lines 
      \belowdisplayskip=0pt%%
      \belowdisplayshortskip=0pt%%
      \noexpand\mypoly
    },
    {Transfer \noexpand\dollars{3000} for trip to Venice},
    { $x\noexpand\cos(x)$ How many suitcases do I need?},
    { What's this going to result in? 
      \belowdisplayskip=0pt%%
      \belowdisplayshortskip=0pt%%
      \noexpand\[ x^2+1\noexpand\]
    }
  }%%
}

\vspace{1cm}

\setagenda{
  title={something else},
  items for the agenda={%%
    {first item},
    {second item}}}

\end{document}
```

Why is it that some math commands work and others don't.  I thought that, because I'm issuing `\expandonce` in the macro used to build the contents of the `tabular` environment, these errors shouldn't arise.

To labor the point a bit more, when I try to look at this in miniature, without all the noise of the `tabular` environment, I get even more confused.

The following MWE compiles fine:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\begin{document}
\let\mytrial\relax
\foreach \x in {$\cos$,
                $x^2+x$}
  {\xdef\mytrial{\x}}
\mytrial
\end{document}
```

So, there's nothing inherently evil about `\cos` and `\xdef` being used together.  But when I try to make this look a bit more like the code above in `\setagenda`, things go awry in ways I can't quite fathom.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\begin{document}
\let\mytrial\relax
\foreach \x in {$\cos$,
                $x^2+x$}
  {\xdef\mytrial{\mytrial\x}}
\mytrial
\end{document}
```

I don't even get an error.  TeX just enters an infinite loop (it's as though there's a LaTeX3'ish quark in there or something).

Well, I  have `\let` something to be `\relax` in there.  So, I tried

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\begin{document}
\def\mytrial{\relax}
%%\def\mytrial{}%%<--- this line works too!
\foreach \x in {$\cos$,
                $x^2+x$}
  {\xdef\mytrial{\mytrial\x}}
\mytrial
\end{document}
```

which does work, which totally flabbergasts me!  How is this last example any different from what I'm doing inside `\setagenda`?  There aren't even any `\expandonce` commands in there to *save* things for later.

My understanding of `\noexpand\x` is that

```
\xdef\mycmd{\noexpand\somecmd}
```

results in

```
\mycmd=\somecmd
```

My understanding of `\expandonce\x` where `\x=\noexpand\cos` is that

```
\xdef\mycmd{\expandonce\x}
```

results in

```
\mycmd=\noexpand\cos
```

So if I've got something like

```
\mycmd=\noexpand\cos
\x=\noexpand\tan
```

and then  try

```
\xdef\mycmd{\expandonce\mycmd \expandonce\x}
```

I expect the result to be

```
\mycmd=\noexpand\cos \noexpand\tan
```

What's happening?  What am I not understanding here?
I guess I should conclude that there's something going on inside the `tabular` environment that I haven't tapped yet with my examples.  But I'm not really sure what that would be.

Comment: Check the details: `\xdef\x{\cos}` doesn't break if `amsmath` is not loaded; it dies otherwise. With `\mycmd=<something>` do you mean that `\mycmd` *expands to* `<something>`?

Comment: @egreg I see what you mean regarding `amsmath`.  I guess I should have written `\mycmd-><something>`. I'm not really sure if I meant *expands*.  I was trying to represent my understand of how `\exandonce` would operate on the contents of the macro `\mycmd`.

Comment: Taking a fresh look at this this morning, I see that I've used `\edef` to define `\list@of@agenda@items`.  If I redefine my key to `items for the agenda/.store in=\list@of@agenda@items,` everything works as expected and I can get rid of the `\noexpand`s at the user level.

Comment: The `\par` that makes your macros fail is because some of them are non long; in particular `\aeset`, but even if you make it `\long`, you'll fail because `\pgffor@normal@list` isn't `\long`. Using `\protected\def\aepar{\par}` can solve the issue, because a `\protected` macro will not be expanded in an `\edef` or `\xdef`.

Comment: @egreg Thank you for the explanation about `\par`.  What's happening with `\let\mytrial\relax` that's causing an infinite loop, but `\def\mytrial{\relax}` doesn't?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are so many things in this question that it's difficult to analyze each one.

Let's tackle the `\cos` problem. Without `amsmath`, its definition is

```
*\show\cos
\cos:
macro:->\mathop {\operator@font cos}\nolimits
```

(here and in what follows I report the output an interactive session; `*` is the prompt in interactive sessions). The expansion of `\operator@font` is `\mathgroup\symoperators` which are two unexpandable tokens. If we try, we get

```
*\xdef\x{\cos}\show\x
> \x=macro:
->\mathop {\mathgroup \symoperators cos}\nolimits .
```

However, when `amsmath` is loaded, the situation is different:

```
*\RequirePackage{amsmath}
*\show\cos
\cos=macro:
->\qopname \relax o{cos}.
```

and `\qopname` is defined via `\DeclareRobustCommand` so it most probably won't survive `\edef` (or `\xdef` which is simply `\global\edef`). Indeed we find

```
% amsopn.sty, line 49:
\DeclareRobustCommand{\qopname}[3]{%
  \mathop{#1\kern\z@\operator@font#3}%
  \csname n#2limits@\endcsname}
```

and

```
% amsopn.sty, line 38:
\def\nolimits@{\@ifnextchar\limits{\nolimits\@gobble}{\nolimits}}
```

which finally is the culprit: it contains `\@ifnextchar`. When doing expanded definitions one should use `\protected@xdef` to overcome the issue. For instance, we'd get

```
*\protected@xdef\x{\cos}\show\x
> \x=macro:
->\protect \qopname  \relax o{cos}.
```

that doesn't show the problem.

What about the `\relax` question? It's easily explained. When a control sequence is unexpandable, `\edef` doesn't do anything with it. And `\relax` is unexpandable. Your code

```
\let\mytrial\relax
\foreach \x in {a,b}
  {\xdef\mytrial{\mytrial\x}}
```

(I use simply `a` and `b` as the tokens you use just make the thing more complicated to follow, but the added complication is irrelevant) is equivalent to

```
\let\mytrial\relax
\xdef\mytrial{\mytrial a}
\xdef\mytrial{\mytrial b}
```

Note that when processing `\edef\cs{<balanced text>}`, first TeX computes the replacement text by doing expansions until unexpandable tokens remain; let's call the result `<balanced text expanded>`; only after doing this, TeX performs the equivalent of `\def\cs{<balanced text expanded>}`. In doing this last step, TeX doesn't interpret the tokens in the replacement text in any way.

After this first `\xdef`, the expansion of `\mytrial` is `\mytrial a`, and now `\mytrial` is not unexpandable any more. So the second `\xdef` will try to expand `\mytrial`; guess what happens? Here it is

```
\mytrial b -> \mytrial ab -> \mytrial aab -> ...
```

because `\edef` and `\xdef` go “all the way”, as already said: they do expansion until only unexpandable tokens remain. Of course, when you have `\def\mytrial{}`, in the first step the expansion will be simply `a` and no infinite loop occurs.

Comment: So are you saying that when I write `\let\mytrial\relax`, since `\relax` is unexpandable, I've created `\mytrial` to be an expandable command sequence that expands to itself?

Comment: @A.Ellett No. In the first `\xdef`, `\mytrial` is not expanded and remains there. But after computing the replacement text, `\mytrial` gets redefined and in the second `\xdef` *this* definition is used. See edit.