# \newcommand for bmatrix of features using pgffor throws missing \endgroup error

Tags: amsmath, matrices, pgffor

There are two parts to this question. Mainly, I'm interested in implementing a `\newcommand` that can take an arbitrary number of arguments to be set in a single column of a matrix.

I tried the following, but it throws a missing `\endgroup` error (and it seems to be a result of `\\`, because taking out `\\` eliminates the error, but then the desired result is not achieved):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand*{\Features}[1]{%
\(%
\begin{bmatrix}%
\foreach \entry in {#1} {\text{\entry}\\}
\end{bmatrix}%
\)%
}

\begin{document}

\Features{--ACC, +PL}

\end{document}
```

Is there an easy way to fix this to make it work as desired?

The second part of the question is *why* this is happening. I'm curious for the sake of learning and for the sake of being able to write better macros in the future, but I haven't been able to figure out what's causing the missing `\endgroup` error.

Comment: The problem is always the same: `\foreach` executes each cycle in a group, so ``\\`` is seen inside that group and the alignment process is messed up.

Comment: @egreg, I'm not sure I am entirely following the explanation, but I take it to mean that there's no easy workaround with `pgffor`? If not, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I came across A. Ellet's [answer here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/135839/32888), which I think is related, but I did not entirely understand what was going on in this answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Enrico Gregorio has already explained the reason in [his comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146463/newcommand-for-bmatrix-of-features-using-pgffor-throws-missing-endgroup-error#comment332045_146463):
`\foreach` puts the body of its loop in a group. That conflicts with the cell grouping of the matrix environment. Another problem, if there is something after the line end that is not expandable (end of group, `\relax`, ...), then a new (empty) line is created.

The following uses the loop to define `\MatrixBody` that contains the lines of the matrix. The chain of `\expandafter` expands `\entry` once. Otherwise the macro `\MatrixBody` would contain `\entry` in each matrix line, undefined after the loop.

Global assignments are only used because of `\g@addto@macro` from LaTeX's kernel that allows to add stuff to a macro. (Local variants are defined by packages, such as `ltxcmds`).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\Features}[1]{%
  \global\let\MatrixBody\@empty
  \foreach \entry in {#1} {%
    \expandafter\g@addto@macro\expandafter\MatrixBody
    \expandafter{%
      \expandafter\text\expandafter{\entry}\\%
    }%
  }%
  \(%
    \begin{bmatrix}%
      \MatrixBody
    \end{bmatrix}%
  \)%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\Features{--ACC, +PL}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `\foreach` executes each cycle in a group. So in your case you're basically doing

```
\(
\begin{bmatrix}
\begingroup\text{--ACC}\\\endgroup
\begingroup\text{+PL}\\\endgroup
\end{bmatrix}
\)
```

which indeed stops with

```
! Missing \endgroup inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \endgroup
```

You have to build the contents of the matrix beforehand. Also using a cycle process that doesn't group is a lost battle anyway, because also table cells are evaluated in a group and `\\` ends it.

Here's an `expl3` based macro.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% the user level command
\NewDocumentCommand{\Features}{ m }
 {
  \adam_features:n { #1 }
 }
% a variable
\seq_new:N \l_adam_items_seq
% the programmer level function
\cs_new_protected:Npn \adam_features:n #1
 {
  % clear the sequence
  \seq_clear:N \l_adam_items_seq
  % do a mapping on the comma list separated input
  % adding the item between \mathrm{ and }
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
   {
    \seq_put_right:Nn \l_adam_items_seq { \mathrm { ##1 } }
   }
  \(
  \begin{bmatrix}
  % deliver the items separated by \\
  \seq_use:Nn \l_adam_items_seq { \\ }
  \end{bmatrix}
  \)
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\Features{-ACC, +PL}

\end{document}
```

Note that I use `\mathrm` rather than `\text`; but it's personal choice.

[image]

Comment: + 1 Thanks! The explanation of the problematic `\foreach` grouping is very clear, though I've gone ahead and accepted Heiko's answer, as I prefer a LaTeX2e solution, at least for the time being. I still haven't had time to try to learn any LaTeX3 syntax. `:)`

Answer (score 1):

I believe I've found an alternative to `pgffor` that is simpler than the solutions given so far. It uses `\forcsvlist` from `etoolbox`, which appears not to suffer from the grouping problem in `pgffor`.

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand*{\textmatrixline}[1]{\text{#1}\\}
\newcommand*{\bigsqbr}[1]{%
  \(%
    \begin{bmatrix}%
      \forcsvlist{\textmatrixline}{#1}
    \end{bmatrix}%
  \)%
}

\begin{document}

\bigsqbr{--ACC, +PL}

\end{document}
```

[image]